# Express passport http-bearer and local

Tags: node.js, express, passport-local, bearer-token

Hello I am trying to implement an auth system with tokens. My approach is the following:

First I authenticate/login the user via `passport-local`, generate a token and send it back to the client. But because I don't use sessions and cookies the user does not get stored in `req.user`.

My question is, if it is possible to call the `passport-http-bearer` strategy right after I authenticated the user with passport-local so the `req.user` is set.

Because right now I have to make another API call to a different route to activate the `passport-http-bearer` strategy so `req.user` is set and stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out [Multiple Strategies in One app](http://aleksandrov.ws/2013/09/12/restful-api-with-nodejs-plus-mongodb/)

I hope this helps.